Converting broom outputs of multiple models into regression tables
For various reasons, I only have access to objects model_coeffs and model_summary below. These form broom::tidy() and broom::glance() objects respectively. In other words, I do not have access to the underlying lm/glm objects, but have access to model_coeffs and model_summary as .csv files. For a reproducible example, I have provided code so that others can get to the same point
library(tidyverse)

pairings <- tidyr::expand_grid(
  lhs = c('vs', 'am'),
  rhs = c('hp', 'hp + drat', 'hp + drat + wt', 'hp + drat + wt + qsec')
)

pairings <- pairings %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    formula = map2(lhs, rhs, ~ as.formula(paste(.x, "~", .y))),
    model = map(formula, ~ glm(.x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mtcars)),
    tidied_model = map(model, \(x) broom::tidy(x, conf.int = T, exp = T)),
    model_summaries = map(model, broom::glance),
    r_squared_nagelkerke = map(model, performance::r2_nagelkerke),
    r_squared_tjur = map(model, performance::r2_tjur),
    model_name = map_chr(formula, deparse),
    model_number = case_when(
      str_count(model_name, "\\+") == 0 ~ 'Model 1',
      str_count(model_name, "\\+") == 1 ~ 'Model 2',
      str_count(model_name, "\\+") == 2 ~ 'Model 3',
      str_count(model_name, "\\+") == 3 ~ 'Model 4'
    )
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-formula, -model)

model_coeffs <- pairings %>% 
  dplyr::select(-model_summaries, -r_squared_nagelkerke, -r_squared_tjur) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(c(tidied_model),   names_repair = "unique") 

model_summary <- pairings %>% 
  dplyr::select(-tidied_model) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(model_summaries, r_squared_nagelkerke, r_squared_tjur))


How can I convert model_coeffs and model_summary into something pretty like this? It does not have to be exactly that, plus it should append some model summary stuff. Can {modelsummary} do this? I tried to follow instructions here but to no avail. 
EDIT: Thank you to @Vincent. Using the {modelsummary} package, you can trick it to believe that it's of class(modelsummary_list)

# Filtering data for outcome 'vs'
model_coeffs_vs <- model_coeffs %>%
  filter(lhs == "vs")
model_summary_vs <- model_summary %>%
  filter(lhs == "vs")

# Creating a list of unique model numbers
model_numbers <- unique(model_coeffs_vs$model_number)

# Creating a list of modelsummary_list objects
model_list <- map(model_numbers, function(model_num) {

  # Extract tidy data
  tidy_data <- model_coeffs_vs %>%
    filter(model_number == !!model_num) %>%
    mutate("OR" = estimate,
           estimate = log(estimate))
  
  # Extract glance data
  glance_data <- model_summary_vs %>%
    filter(model_number == !!model_num) %>%
    select(-c(lhs, rhs, model_number, model_name)) %>%
    rename(
      `Sample size` = nobs,
      "Pseduo R<sup>2</sup> (Nagelkerke)" = r_squared_nagelkerke, 
      "Pseudo R<sup>2</sup> (Tjur)" = r_squared_tjur)
  
  # Create the modelsummary_list object
  mod <- list(
    tidy = tidy_data,
    glance = glance_data
  )
  
  class(mod) <- "modelsummary_list"
  
  return(mod)
})

# Naming models with model numbers
names(model_list) <- set_names(model_numbers)

# Use modelsummary to summarize the models

modelsummary(model_list,
             shape = term ~ model + statistic,
             coef_omit = "Intercept",
             statistic = c("Odds ratio" = "OR", 
                           "S.E." = "std.error"),
             coef_rename = c(
               "drat" = "Rear axle ratio", 
                             "hp" = "Horsepower",
                             "wt" = "Weight",
                             "qsec" = "1/4 mile time"),
             notes = list('Text of the first note.', 
                          'Text of the second note.')
)


The easiest way to do this might be to store your data in a format that modelsummary will automatically recognize: a modelsummary_list object. This strategy is described here:
https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/modelsummary_extension.html
Here’s a minimal example example:
library(modelsummary)

models <- list(
    glm(am ~ hp, data = mtcars, family = binomial),
    glm(am ~ hp + wt, data = mtcars, family = binomial)
)

results <- list()
for (i in seq_along(models)) {
    results[[i]] <- list()
    class(results[[i]]) <- "modelsummary_list"
    results[[i]][["tidy"]] <- data.frame(
        "term" = names(coef(models[[i]])),
        "estimate" = coef(models[[i]]),
        "OR" = exp(coef(models[[i]])),
        "std.error" = sqrt(diag(vcov(models[[i]]))))
    results[[i]][["glance"]] <- data.frame(nobs = nobs(models[[i]]))
}

modelsummary(results,
    statistic = c("OR", "std.error"),
    shape = term ~ model + statistic)

+-------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+
|             | (1)                    | (2)                           |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+
|             | Est.   | OR    | S.E.  | Est.   | OR           | S.E.  |
+=============+========+=======+=======+========+==============+=======+
| (Intercept) | 0.777  | 2.174 | 0.915 | 18.866 | 1.561455e+08 | 7.444 |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+
| hp          | -0.008 | 0.992 | 0.006 | 0.036  | 1.037000e+00 | 0.018 |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+
| wt          |        |       |       | -8.083 | 0.000000e+00 | 3.069 |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+
| Num.Obs.    | 32     |       |       | 32     |              |       |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+ 


Thank you for your response! I should have been clearer that in my use case, I no longer have access to the data, I can only access the csv (i.e., objects model_coeffs and model_summary) as tibbles once imported into R. Therefore, I cannot see how I could run the models <- list(
glm(am ~ hp, data = mtcars, family = binomial),
glm(am ~ hp + wt, data = mtcars, family = binomial)
) bit you suggest. This is just a permissions thing where the data is only available through a secure server and any summary statistics/models needs to be 'approved' and 'cleared' by an independent service.

Yes, I understood that. This is just a minimal example. The key is that each model needs to be a different object of class modelsummary_list(), with a tidy and a glance element. Here, I build those individual objects with coef(models[[i]]), but you can supply data from any format you have accessible.

Thank you very much. I've edited the post in light of your suggestions. The package is amazing! When the table ahas been re-shaped, is there anyway to align the model summary stats to the centre: e.g. like this rather than like this

Great! Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to achieve this right now. I opened an issue on Github, but this might be tricky... https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/769
